# How do I delete a row from my database based on a post value within the row

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, forms

I have a dynamic form where users can add rows and submit that data to a database and when users return to the form page the data that was submitted pre-populates the form to which they can update the data or add more rows of data.

If a user wants to delete a row from the database I have a delete button that changes the 'is_active' form value from 'yes' to 'no' for that particular row and when they submit the form, I want to delete the row that has the 'is_active' post value of 'no'.

I am using $wpdb to replace the rows and also to delete them. The code that I have commented out ends up deleting all rows in the table instead of just the ones with the is_active post value of 'no'.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once '../../../wp-load.php';

    global $wpdb;
    $newdb = new wpdb( 'user' , 'pass' , 'table' , 'localhost' );

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $county = $_POST['county'];
        $street = $_POST['street'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $ward = $_POST['ward'];
        $precinct = $_POST['precinct'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $is_active = $_POST['is_active'];


        if(is_array($_POST)) {
            foreach($username as $index => $value) {
              if   (in_array("no", $_POST['is_active'], TRUE))
              { 
              /*  $newdb->delete( 'member_lists', array( 'id' => $id[$index])); */
                        $newdb->query( 
                            $newdb->prepare( 
                                    "
                                     DELETE FROM $newdb->member_lists
                                     WHERE id = $id[$index]
                                     AND $is_active[$index] = 'no'
                                    " 
                                    )
                        ); 

                       $newdb->replace( 'member_lists', 
                array( 
                        'id' => $id[$index],
                        'username' => $value, 
                        'first_name' => $first_name[$index],
                        'last_name' => $last_name[$index],
                        'county' => $county[$index],
                        'street' => $street[$index],
                        'city' => $city[$index],
                        'ward' => $ward[$index],
                        'precinct' => $precinct[$index]

                    ), 
                    array( 
                        '%s',
                        '%s', 
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                    ) 
);

                $wpdb->show_errors();

              }
                else{
                $newdb->replace( 'member_lists', 
                array( 
                        'id' => $id[$index],
                        'username' => $value, 
                        'first_name' => $first_name[$index],
                        'last_name' => $last_name[$index],
                        'county' => $county[$index],
                        'street' => $street[$index],
                        'city' => $city[$index],
                        'ward' => $ward[$index],
                        'precinct' => $precinct[$index]

                    ), 
                    array( 
                        '%s',
                        '%s', 
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                    ) 
);

                $wpdb->show_errors();
                }

            }   
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: `$newdb->query( 
                            $newdb->prepare(` < That doesn't look right to me. You're querying but then preparing, I don't get that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner apparently thats how they do it in their api https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare .the problem is values are still directly injected in the statement ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I picked that up from the Class Reference codex on wpdb. I feel like $newdb->delete is a better idea, I just can't figure out how to only delete the one row instead of all rows when a single instance of 'no' is in the array.

Comment: @Kevin Oh, I see. Thanks for that. I don't know Wordpress, so my bad. One never ceases to learn :) I thought it was the same syntax as a prepared statement from php.net that I know.

Comment: @Holodout I take it that the input(s) for `$_POST['is_active']` is/are checkboxes in a form? If so, maybe something isn't right in there. Do they have the same name attribute and using `[]` to treat them as arrays?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It is actually a hidden input where I switch the value if a user clicks on the delete row button on the form. It hides the row and changes the value. `<td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" class="form-control active" name="is_active[]" id="is_active" value="yes"></td>`

Comment: i'm not sure why you'd have the need to iterate the whole users again to update, delete, and replace. i feel your UI only has one submit button to do all and it makes your logic in needlessly complicated, delegate each task to do just one operation. heck even google mail has different buttons to delete, add, and other operations, don't stuff everything into one submission

Comment: You're right, the form only has one submit button that's why it's written that way. A single commit/delete button per row would be a better idea for simplifying the tasks. For this particular instance it has to be a single button update. I might try and see if I can swing making the delete button per row submit a single request.

Comment: you could either put a delete button somewhere in the row, make the deletion using the id of the user, or for multiple delete just use the checkbox style like @FunkFortyNiner alluded to. you'd only need the id, and avoids the iteration for all the users. you'll only handle the ones selected by the user. deleting individually will be simpler though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not employ this method but for the sake of answering the question, here is the solution I came up with.

Instead of trying to read the value of "is_active" before insert/update and then deleting the entry from the database, what I did was submit that value to the database and then after my initial 'replace' query, I run a second query where I delete from the database any row where the value of 'is_active' is 'no'.

Seeing as that any row where 'is_active' is marked as 'no' for deletion I don't want it in the database at all so I don't bother with reading the row based on the index.

```
<?php
    require_once '../../../wp-load.php';

    global $wpdb;
    $newdb = new wpdb( 'user' , 'pass' , 'table' , 'localhost' );

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $county = $_POST['county'];
        $street = $_POST['street'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $ward = $_POST['ward'];
        $precinct = $_POST['precinct'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $is_active = $_POST['is_active'];


        if(is_array($_POST)) {
            foreach($username as $index => $value) {

                $newdb->replace( 'member_lists', 
                array( 
                        'id' => $id[$index],
                        'username' => $value, 
                        'first_name' => $first_name[$index],
                        'last_name' => $last_name[$index],
                        'county' => $county[$index],
                        'street' => $street[$index],
                        'city' => $city[$index],
                        'ward' => $ward[$index],
                        'precinct' => $precinct[$index],
                        'is_active' => $is_active[$index]

                    ), 
                    array( 
                        '%s',
                        '%s', 
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                    ) 
);

                $newdb->show_errors();



            }


        } 

        if ($newdb) {
$newdb->delete('member_lists', array('is_active' => "no"));
            wp_redirect('http://website.com/home/list-has-been-updated/');

}
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
change this string only
"DELETE FROM $newdb->member_lists WHERE id = $id[$index] AND $is_active[$index] = 'no'"
```

to this and try

```
"DELETE FROM ".$newdb->member_lists." WHERE id = ".$id[$index]." AND ".$is_active[$index]." = 'no';"
```

Comment: Tried that, the rows still update and insert but not delete.